# Get xpath of a given element in XSLT Python

Tags: python, xml, xslt

I am trying to search for an element and return the full xpath to that element in XSLT.

For example, I have an XSLT file like this:

```
<title>
  <header>
    <info1>A</info1>
    <info2>B</info2>
  </header>
</title>
```

I'm looking for a function where I can parse the XSLT file, enter something like:

```
info1
```

and return:

```
title/header/info1
```

If there is more than one element with that tag, then I want to return all of them.

I've tried the methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936531/how-to-get-path-of-all-elements-in-lxml-with-attribute) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351494/getting-the-path-of-an-xml-node-in-python) but they don't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems that the example you've chosen are attribute based (condition starting with `@`). Try without the `@`.

Comment: I used this [XPath tester](http://xpather.com/) and achieved to isolate the node with: `//*[text()="A"]`. After that you have to rebuild the path from this node until the root (but in reverse) by getting the parent of each node until you reach the root.

Comment: I found that XPath tester as well! Unfortunately, my goal here is to automate the process of rebuilding the path from element to root, rather than manually going element by element.

Comment: By automate you mean in your Python script? You can do it recursively.

Comment: Or even in a loop. Build a list of tags, reverse it, then join with `/`

Comment: Please explain why the answers to the linked questions "don't seem to work".

Answer (score 2):

Using lxml

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '''<title>
  <header>
    <info1>A</info1>
    <info2>B</info2>
    <jack>
        <info1>AA</info1>
    </jack>
  </header>
</title>'''

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
elements = root.findall('.//info1')
for e in elements:
    print(tree.getpath(e))
```

output

```
/title/header/info1
/title/header/jack/info1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this through XSLT, try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:param name="element-name">info1</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[name()=$element-name]">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>    
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```